# Colorize logo images with Photoshop or paint.NET

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency, paint.net

I am looking for a way to colorize images like on this page:

http://pinetools.com/colorize-image

You have an image with transparency, then the remaining pixels are converted to the specified color. Notice: half colored pixels as well are only colored half or with opacity 0.5. So it does not look ugly or pixelated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colorizing website does actually a complex job. It saves the transparency ie.the alpha values stay unchanged, but the new color is an adjustable mix of original color and selected new color.

Photoshop has got a very simple to use method in another answer. Paint.NET hasn't layer styles, so the proposed method is not available there.

For Paint.NET there are available several colorizing plugins. I haven't tried all of them, only a few. Those are made for adjusting a selectable color range (=change hue, saturation, brightness or transparency). But anyway, the job can be done with them, too. An example:

A random multicolour image with transparency:

[image]

Duplicate the image layer and make the copy 50% grey. Use the curves adjustment in RGB-mode:

[image]

If no mixing with the original is needed, there's no need to make a copy. Make the original layer grey.

Colorize the grey with a plugin:

[image]

Plugin = TR's ColorizerHMS

Adjust the transparency of the colorized layer to define the mix (not asked, but surprising effects are available by changing the blending mode - well worth to try!)

[image]

Finally merge the layers if you want to fix the effect to non-adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

In photoshop double click the image layer and apply color overlay. That's it.

Comment: A right answer, but quite impossible for beginners without a  couple of screenshots. Still worth of+1.

Comment: I think it is the function symbol at the bottom right `fx`

Comment: @Toskan That's ok. After selecting Color Overlay, you can select the color and mix.